# Is it possible to communicate one resource server with another using Spring OAuth2RestTemplate

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I am using OAuth2RestTemplate to communicate with Authorization Server, but I am unable to succeed to communicate from one resource server to another.

For Example:
Let's say I have Profile micro service (resource server) needs to talk to (get some info) User service (another resource server).

Both services are annotated with @EnableResourceServer.

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth2 protocoll itself does not include a spec for resource servers communicating with each other. In the sense of the protocoll the requesting ressource server has the role of a client.

I assume in your case you want the 2nd ressource server to authenticate/autorize the original user on whose behalf the request to the 1st ressource server was send(?). In this case all you would have to do is to forward the access token received by the 1st ressource server to the 2nd ressource server.

This can either be done by a custom filter that reads the access token from the incoming requests and adds it to outgoing requests or by using the Spring OAuth2 Client features.

Comment: can you elaborate on the "using the Spring OAuth2 Client features"? This is the path I've been trying to follow, utilizing the OAuth2RestTemplate but it doesn't seem to be getting the access_token from the OAuth2ClientContext as I expect. This leads to it trying to obtain an authorization_code grant type, which ultimately causes a 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval'.

Comment: I was able to grab the access token info off the RequestContextHolder (e.g. RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes().getAttribute(OAuth2AuthenticationDetails.ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST) and RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes().getAttribute(OAuth2AuthenticationDetails.ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE, RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST)) but this seems a very fragile way to do this.